matplotlib's pyplot.show works from Python's Docker image but doesn't work with a custom Docker image built from the same Python image
Context
I'm looking to set up a development environment for a Python project that uses matplotlib. Things work fine and I am able to see the plot when I run the default Docker image from Dockerhub as:
docker run -v ./:/work -w /work python:3.11 pip install -r requirements.txt && python3 main.py
main.py
# importing the required module 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
    
# x axis values 
x = [1,2,3] 
# corresponding y axis values 
y = [2,4,1] 
    
# plotting the points 
plt.plot(x, y) 
    
# naming the x axis 
plt.xlabel('x - axis') 
# naming the y axis 
plt.ylabel('y - axis') 
    
# giving a title to my graph 
plt.title('My first graph!') 
    
# function to show the plot 
plt.show() 

However, this would need downloading and installing packages with every run. To address this, I created a Dockerfile that does a pip install when building a custom image so that my code can be executed without a pip install every time. I can rebuild the custom image anytime my requirements.txt changes. My Dockerfile looks like:
FROM python:3.11

WORKDIR /work
COPY . .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python3", "main.py"]

I build the image as:
docker build -t py-polygon:0.01 .
and run it as:
docker run py-polygon:0.01
In this case, a plot isn't shown on my display.
I'm running this on an Arch Linux box, in case it's relevant.
Question
Why does the plot work when using the docker image from Dockerhub but it doesn't work when using a custom image built from the same image? Am I missing something?

I wouldn't expect either setup to be able to access the host's display; the container doesn't normally have access to things like the X socket file.  Can you use Python without Docker here, maybe installing packages into a virtual environment?

@DavidMaze The whole point of using Docker is to standardize development environments across teams such that all supporting software and configuration related to this particular Python app is uniform for everyone regardless of what machine they are on. VMs hog resources and cannot be standardized. I just updated the context with a sample code that works for python:3.11 docker image but doesn't give any output for a custom image.
